# Compact imbedding for weight space

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, sobolev-spaces

We begin with some definitions. Let $\gamma  \geqslant 1,\,p \in \left[ {1,\infty } \right)$, we define
$$L_\gamma ^p\left( {0,1} \right) = \left\{ {v:\left( {0,1} \right) \to \mathbb{R}:{{\left\| v \right\|}_p} = {{\left( {\int_0^1 {{x^\gamma }{{\left| {v\left( x \right)} \right|}^p}{\text{d}}x} } \right)}^{\frac{1}{p}}} < \infty } \right\},$$

$$W_\gamma ^{1,2}\left( {0,1} \right) = \left\{ {v \in L_\gamma ^2\left( {0,1} \right):{v_x} \in L_\gamma ^2\left( {0,1} \right)} \right\},$$
with
$${\left\| v \right\|_{W_\gamma ^{1,2}}} = \sqrt {\left\| v \right\|_2^2 + \left\| {{v_x}} \right\|_2^2} .$$
With some elementary inequalities, I can prove that $W_\gamma ^{1,2}\left( {0,1} \right) \hookrightarrow L_\gamma ^p\left( {0,1} \right)$ is continuous with some $p \in \left[ {1,{\gamma ^*}} \right)$. But I don't have any idea to prove the compact embedding from $W_\gamma ^{1,2}\left( {0,1} \right)$ to $L_\gamma ^p\left( {0,1} \right)$.  How can we do it?

Comment: If you have continuity and just need to add compactness you could try something like using compactness on each $ [\epsilon,1]$ by usual results and then use diagonal argument.  This would give compactness unless stuff concentrates and zero and so maybe you just need to rule that out...

Comment: another comment... might we worth looking at a scalilng $ \phi(\lambda x)$ and sending $ \lambda \rightarrow \infty$  before doing anything...to get an idea of what the result should be.

Comment: Thank you for your help. We consider a bounded sequence $\left\{ {{u_n}} \right\} \subset W_\gamma ^{1,2}$. We have ${H^1}\left( {\varepsilon ,1} \right) \hookrightarrow \hookrightarrow  C\left( {\left[ {\varepsilon ,1} \right]} \right)$. If we use diagonal argument, we can find $u \in C\left( {\left( {0,1} \right]} \right)$ such that ${\left\| {{u_{{n_k}}} - u} \right\|_{C\left( {\left[ {\varepsilon ,1} \right]} \right)}} \to 0$. But I cant prove that $u \in L_\gamma ^p\left( {0,1} \right)$ and ${\left\| {{u_{{n_k}}} - u} \right\|_{L_\gamma ^p}} \to 0$. Can you help me?

Comment: whats $\gamma^*$?

Comment: We have $W_\gamma ^{1,2}\left( {0,1} \right) \hookrightarrow L_\gamma ^p\left( {0,1} \right)$ is continuous  provided by $p \in \left( {2,{\gamma _*}} \right)$.

Comment: so $ \gamma^*$ is something you can compute or what is it?

Comment: so are you restricting $ p$ to $ 2 \le p \le \frac{2(\gamma+1)}{\gamma-1}$ ?

Comment: I can compute $\gamma_*$ and I restricted $p < {\gamma _*} = \frac{{2\left( {\gamma  + 1} \right)}}{\gamma }$.

Comment: i seem to have a different range of $p$ then you.  But either way to prove compactness for $p<\gamma^*$  can you not break the integral up into a piece on $[0,\epsilon]$ and then the other portion.  On the other portion you should have convergence in norm.  On the small interval use Holder inequality and fact you have continuity of a slightly larger range of $p$;  this should show that you cannot have concentration at $x=0$ for $p<\gamma^*$.

Comment: So we don't have any compact imbedding???

Comment: If you have continuous imbedding for $ p = \gamma^*$   then you should have compactness for $p$ slightly less.  To try and prove when you are trying to prove convergence in norm for $L^p$  break interval up as mentioned above.  Apply Holder on the small portion and you should get an $\epsilon$ factor from Holder...

Comment: Thank you a  lot for your help.